# Browser console showing duplicate fields when submitting

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a script that updates the data from a form into a MySQL table (see code below). But when I cleck on the "Save" button
the script runs but in the browser console I see the following:

CONSOLE RESULT

```
HotelID: EXBHX
CompanyImage: 
RoomID: 
RecordID: 
CompanyImage: 
ClientName: 
FromDate: 
RoomFromTimeH: 
ToDate: 
RoomToTimeH: 
FromDisplayTimeH: 0
FromDisplayTimeM: 0
DisplayText: 
image_field: (binary)
MultiRoomLevel: 2
MultiDisplayLevel: 2
MultiBoardLevel: 1
// SPACE INSERTED FOR EASY READING
RecordID: 46359
RoomID: 2
RoomName: Watt  Suite
CompanyImage: undefined
ClientName: Birds Eye
RoomFromDate: 13-09-2019
RoomToDate: 21-09-2019
RoomFromTimeH: 07
RoomFromTimeM: 07
RoomToTimeH: 18
RoomToTimeM: 17
FromDisplayTimeH: 0
FromDisplayTimeM: 0
DisplayText: 
ClientImageName: C:\fakepath\coffeecup.jpg
RoomLevel: 4
DisplayLevel: 4
BoardLevel: 0
image_field: undefined
```

Can anyone see why the console is echoing out the form fields twice when I would expect to see the last section starting from "RecordID: 46359".

FORM

```
<form  name="Form3" id="update_record" autocomplete="off"  enctype="multipart/form-data" role="form" data-toggle="validator">
<button class="btn btn-success btn-xs submit-button" type="submit" >Save</button>
</form>
```

UPDATE SCRIPT

```
$("#update_record").submit(function(event){ 
var hotelid = "<?php echo $_SESSION['_amember_user']['hotelid'];?>";
var recordid            = $('#EditRecordID').val();
var roomid              = $('#EditRoomID').val();
var roomname            = $('#EditRoomName').val();
var companyimage        = $('#Editcompany_image_1').val();
var clientname          = $('#EditClientName').val();
var fromdate            = $('#EditRoomFromDate').val();
var fromhours           = $('#EditRoomFromTimeH').val();
var frommins            = $('#EditRoomFromTimeM').val();
var todate              = $('#EditRoomToDate').val();
var tohours             = $('#EditRoomToTimeH').val();
var tomins              = $('#EditRoomToTimeM').val();
var fromdisplaytimeh    = $('#EditFromDisplayTimeH').val();
var fromdisplaytimem    = $('#EditFromDisplayTimeM').val();
var displaytext         = $('#EditDisplayText').val();
var lookupimage         = $('#EditBrowse').val();
var roomlevel           = $('input[name=EditRoomLevel]:checked', '#update_record').val()
var displaylevel        = $('input[name=EditDisplayLevel]:checked', '#update_record').val()
var boardlevel          = $('input[name=EditBoardLevel]:checked', '#update_record').val()
event.preventDefault();
var form = $('form')[3];
var formData = new FormData(form);

formData.append("RecordID", recordid);
formData.append("RoomID", roomid);
formData.append("RoomName", roomname);
formData.append("CompanyImage", companyimage);
formData.append("ClientName", clientname);
formData.append("RoomFromDate", fromdate);
formData.append("RoomToDate", todate);
formData.append("RoomFromTimeH", fromhours);
formData.append("RoomFromTimeM", frommins);
formData.append("RoomToTimeH", tohours);
formData.append("RoomToTimeM", tomins);
formData.append("FromDisplayTimeH", fromdisplaytimeh);
formData.append("FromDisplayTimeM", fromdisplaytimem);
formData.append("DisplayText", displaytext);
formData.append("ClientImageName", lookupimage);
formData.append("RoomLevel", roomlevel);
formData.append("DisplayLevel", displaylevel);
formData.append("BoardLevel", boardlevel);
formData.append('image_field', $('input[type=file]')[0].files[0]);

$(".progress-bar").animate({
width: "100%"
}, 2500);
$.ajax({
    url:"edit_conference.php",
    data: formData,
    type: 'POST',
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,

    }).done(function(response){
    console.log("FORMDATA", formData);
    $('.progress-bar').attr('style', "width: 0%");
    $("#Editpreviewtext").html("");
    $("#EditPreview").html("");
    $('#insert_promotion')[0].reset();
    $(this).closest('form').find("input[type=text], textarea").val("");
    $('#EditRoomFromDate').datepicker('setDate', null);
    $('#EditRoomToDate').datepicker('setDate', null);
    select_box = document.getElementById("EditRoomFromTimeH");
    select_box.selectedIndex = "00";
    select_box = document.getElementById("EditRoomFromTimeM");
    select_box.selectedIndex = "00";
    select_box = document.getElementById("EditRoomToTimeH");
    select_box.selectedIndex = -1;
    select_box = document.getElementById("EditRoomToTimeM");
    select_box.selectedIndex = -1;
    $('#EditRoomLevel_1').prop('checked', false);
    $('#EditRoomLevel_2').prop('checked', true);
    $('#EditRoomLevel_3').prop('checked', false);
    $('#EditRoomLevel_4').prop('checked', false);
    $('#EditDisplayLevel_1').prop('checked', false);
    $('#EditDisplayLevel_2').prop('checked', true);
    $('#EditDisplayLevel_3').prop('checked', false);
    $('#EditDisplayLevel_4').prop('checked', false);
    $('#EditBoardLevel_1').prop('checked', true);
    $('#EditBoardLevel_2').prop('checked', false);
    $("#ShowBar").hide();
    $('#open_edit_data_modal').modal("hide");
    //setTimeout(function(){// wait for 5 secs(2)
    location.reload(); // then reload the page.(3)
    // END SCREEN REFRESH

});
});
```

Comment: When you pass the form element into `new FormData(form)` it automatically includes all the named fields and associated values/files in the form. Doing all the manual appends is redundant

Comment: @charlietfl Hi and many thanks for your response. I have removed all the manual appends but now none of the forms data gets passed to the Ajax function. All I see in the browser console is a list of the form field names. Any ideas?

Comment: Put a demo together that reproduces problem. Are those ID's in `$('form')[3]`? Could try doing `var form = this` instead since `this` is the form element the submit event occurs on